# Debugging my cron application

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have a code like this :

```
set -e
set -x
folderName=$(echo `date +%Y/%m/%d/`);
fileName=x.x.x.x.x.x.x.log 
cp x.x.x.x.x.x/$1 $fileName  
gzip $fileName  
s3cmd put $fileName.gz s3://x.x.x.x.x/$folderName    
rm $fileName.gz
```

This is working fine if I run like this :

```
./shell logfilelocation
```

And when I added into the crontab like this :

```
* * * * * /home/x.x.x/testing/s3 -f x.x.x.log >> /tmp/mys3Log
```

And I waited! The file `mys3Log` gets created. But there is no content in it! I expect the result of command execution ( as I have used `set -e ; set -x` in my code ) should go into the `mys3Log` file as I'm doing a redirect there.

But something is going wrong. I'm very new to bash programming and cron.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cron` don't have the same environment like in interactive shell, so at the beginning of the script, after the shebang, add :

```
source ~/.bashrc || source /etc/profile
```

And remove `set -e` to see what's going on.

In your `crontab`, to log errors & output (`STDERR`, `STDOUT`), you need to do :

```
* * * * * /home/x.x.x/testing/s3 -f x.x.x.log >> /tmp/mys3Log 2>&1
```

Moreover, on line 4 of your script, you are using the variable `$name` thats is never declared.

Last but not least, like Janauary said, add the `#!/bin/bash` shegang on the first line and ensure that your script have executable rights. : `chmod +x script.sh`

Comment: The line `source ~/.bashrc || source /etc/profile` should be added into cron file?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you didn't answer my comment question.

Comment: I'm getting an error as `s3cmd: command not found` in my cron log file.

Comment: Yes it is working interactive shell and also in my shell script. Only fails in the `crontab`.

Comment: So in your script, put the full PATH for `s3cmd`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer, the cron works in different environment than your shell. Which means that the environment variables would differ in shell. For eg:

In shell:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin
```

Whereas in if you run the following in cron:

```
* * * * * echo $PATH > path.out
```

you'll get `/usr/bin:/bin`.

Find out where is your s3cmd executable using the command `which s3cmd` and then modify the cron accordingly. Eg:

```
$ which s3cmd
/usr/local/bin/s3cmd
```

Then, cron should look like:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin
* * * * * echo $PATH > path.out
```